# Meteor and a different sort of database

Tags: database, meteor

> You can substitute another database for MongoDB by providing a server-side database driver and/or a client-side cache that implements an alternative API. The mongo-livedata is a good starting point for such a project.

I'm interested in Meteor, but no in Mongo DB. I'm curious about how to hook up a database that my clients use, which is usually Oracle, MySQL, or Postgres.

I have no idea what 'the mongo-livedata' is, and Google shows the above reference is the only reference on meteor.com -- could you please tell explain, ad offer any details you have for a walk-through on this matter? It would be a shame to only have access to Mongo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteors *mongo-livedata* uses a "builtin" mongoDB library, database, collection and setup handled by the meteor/node runtime itself.

Meteor does not directly support other databases by now when it comes to using the `Collections` API. But it should be possible to write an own *connector* which implements `Collections`.

Meteor is in an early state right now - so be aware that API and best pactises may still change fundamentally!

Comment: I appreciate that, and hope that development is pursued using a db abstraction layer, and not being hard-coded to Mongo.

Comment: Actually `Collections` _are_ an abstraction to document based database storage. I'm sure there will be a coupled of supported databases as soon as Meteor hits the masses.

Comment: any link with databases supported by meteor? so we can follow it